# mysqldump dumps different data with and without --no-create-info

Tags: mysql, mysqldump, character-set, encoding, utf-8

`mysqldump` dumps different representations of data when called with/without `--no-create-info`.

## Test case

First, create the `test` table and populate it with interesting data.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `value` longtext
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;

-- insert 'crème'
insert into test values(UNHEX('6372C3A86D65'));
```

Then, dump the data using with and without `--no-create-info`:

```bash
mysqldump test_db test > dump_test.sql
mysqldump --no-create-info test_db test > dump_test2.sql
```

These files encode **crème** differently:

- `dump_test.sql` encodes it as `0x6372C3A86D65` (`è` is `0xC3A8`)
- `dump_test2.sql` encodes it as `0x63725CE86D65` (`è` is `0x5CE8`)

Restoring the dump from `dump_test.sql` works correctly, a complete row is restored:

```bash
mysql test_db < dump_test.sql
```

Restoring the dump from `dump_test2.sql` produces an incorrect result where data is truncated to just `cr` (`0x6372`). **Note that structure of the table is the same**:

```bash
mysql test_db < dump_test2.sql
```

No error nor warning is given. These two files differ - besides encoding of `crème` - only by:

```sql
-- Table structure for table `test`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `test`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!50503 SET character_set_client = utf8mb4 */;
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `value` longtext
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client */;

--
```

## Question

Why does this happen? Is it documented anywhere? Can I/how can I correctly restore the dump created with `--no-create-info` data?

## Additional info

```bash
# mysqldump used to dump the database
$ mysqldump -V
mysqldump  Ver 8.0.22-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
# Server
version_component: Percona Server (GPL), Release '35', Revision '5688520'
version: 5.7.32-35
```

Comment: `5CE8` is `\è` when using character set latin1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dumping using [`--hex-blob`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_hex-blob)

```
mysqldump --hex-blob test_db test > dump_test.sql
mysqldump --hex-blob --no-create-info test_db test > dump_test2.sql
```

Please let us know if the hex value remains the same between the two dumps.

## UPDATE 2021-01-08 14:15 EST

### Try changing character set

The [MySQL Docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_default-character-set) say that mysqldump will use `utf8` if not specified

> Internationalization Options The following options change how the
> mysqldump command represents character data with national language
> settings.
>
> --character-sets-dir=dir_name
>
> The directory where character sets are installed. See Section 10.15,
> “Character Set Configuration”.
>
> --default-character-set=charset_name
>
> Use charset_name as the default character set. See Section 10.15,
> “Character Set Configuration”. If no character set is specified,
> mysqldump uses utf8.
>
> --no-set-names, -N
>
> Turns off the --set-charset setting, the same as specifying
> --skip-set-charset.
>
> --set-charset
>
> Write SET NAMES default_character_set to the output. This option is
> enabled by default. To suppress the SET NAMES statement, use
> --skip-set-charset.

Just add `-N` to ignore character sets or use `--set-charset` to explicitly name the character set you want to use when loading the dump in.

Comment: This seems to have no effect. Both `diff`s between the two sets of files (with `--hex-blob` and without, with and without `--no-create-info`) are the same (except for the timestamps). According to `man mysqldump` this affects binar-ish data, is `longtext` considered binary?

Comment: Scrap my previous comment. This has helped. `mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8 --no-create-info test_db test > test.sql`. Now, any idea why `--no-create-info` would turn off utf8?

Comment: Perhaps (Probably) to allow for an agnostic loading of data ? This would put the responsibility of the character set more in your realm. With a create table statement included, the character set might get added in the metacommands. (Just an off-the-top-of-my-head guess)